# VSCode Cannot Execute Julia FIles

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

I've scoured other forums that talk about this problem and have tried all of the recommendations I've found, but I cannot seem to get VSCode to recognize my Julia.exe path and execute commands in a .jl file. Every time I run even a simple .jl file, I get /bin/sh: julia: command not found (pictured below).
[image]

I have ensured that the executable path is set properly in the .json file, and have tried moving the executable to other locations (using an M1 Mac), but it seems it still cannot find/recognize the Julia.exe:
[image]

I have even tried just pointing to the binary folder /bin, and /bin/julia.exe (with the extension), and though VSCode does not generate the error when it cannot confirm the .exe path, the actual code still generates the error above.

I'm at my wits end here. I'm sure it's a simple answer that someone could spot in a second, or know the troubleshooting for, but I've never had this issue to this degree before with installing other languages like Kotlin. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/#optional_add_julia_to_path ?

Comment: Cool - perhaps add an answer? 

Answer (score 1):

Problem was fixed by the MacOS recommendation found here:
julialang.org/downloads/platform/#optional_add_julia_to_path

Copying the binary .exe elsewhere (outside of /Applications) and changing the executable path in VSCode fixed the issue.